# Expected value of the longest segment of a broken stick (not using intergrals!)

Tags: probability

I am self-studying probability and my textbook have the following question:

Given a stick[1,....,n] with n units, we break the stick at some random point and take the largest piece for ourselves. What will be the expected size of our piece?

This seems to be a pretty classic expectation problem and I've read many solutions online, problem is *they all use integrals which I have yet to study.*

The formula I know for expected size:
$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i \in \Omega} X(i) P(i)$

When $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable, and $P$ denotes the probability.

Intuitively I understand that the largest piece will always be between $[\frac{1}{2}, .. , 1]$, and due to uniformed distribution the result will be $\frac{3}{4}$, but I still need help working on how to write my answer in a good manner (textbook does not have answers).

I can define a random variable:

$  X(i) =
\begin{cases}
1-i,  & \text{if $i < \frac{1}{2}$} \\
i & \text{if $i \geq \frac{1}{2}$}
\end{cases}$

But how do I progress from here using the formula I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question wether you are dealing with "discrete" stick of length $n$ that one is only allowed to break at integer points $0,1,\ldots n$, or  a unit stick which one is allowed to break "uniformly at random".

1) In the discrete case, the answer is given by the formula you give: probability of any particular breaking point being chosen is $\frac{1}{n+1}$, and the size of the **smaller piece** is (assuming $n=2k+1$ is odd)

$$n-E(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}(0+1+\ldots +k-1+k+k+(k-1)+(k-2)+\ldots +1+0)=\frac{k(k+1)}{n+1}$$

which is $\frac{(n^2-1)}{4(n+1)}$, and the expected size of bigger piece is $E(n)=n-\frac{(n^2-1)}{4(n+1)}$.

(Note: if your stick can only be broken at $1, 2, \ldots, n$ then the denominator is $n$ instead of $n+1$, $E(n)=n-\frac{(n^2-1)}{4n)}$ for odd $n$.)

Now you can get the answer to the "continuous uniform stick" case by rescaling the discrete stick to be of size 1, and observing that the "discrete distribution with $n+1$ equally spaced probabilities of $1/(n+1)$ converges (in some sense) to the uniform distribution as $n$ goes to infinity". Then the expected size of the biggest piece which after rescaling is $\frac{E(n)}{n}$ is converging to the answer in the continuous case - namely $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{(n^2-1)}{4(n+1)n} )=3/4$.

The problem with the above is that not only do you need to know how to take limits, you also need to know what "converges in appropriate sense" means for a sequence of probability distributions, which is probably harder than integration.

2) One approach to the continuous stick question is to argue by conditioning and symmetry. We argue that the expected size of the smaller piece is 1/4 in the following way:

a) With probability 1/2, you pick break point $x$ in the $[0,1/2]$ part of the stick. Then the smaller piece is $x$. Since (conditioned on landing in $[0, 1/2]$) we have picked $x$ uniformly from $[0, 1/2]$, values $x$ and $1/2-x$ are equally likely and the expected value of $x$ is $1/4$.

b) With probability 1/2, you pick break point $x$ in the $[1/2, 1]$ part of the stick. Then the smaller piece is $y=1-x$, which is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1/2]$. By the argument above, expected value of $y$ is $1/4$.

The overall expected value is weighted sum of the two sub-cases, weighted by their probability, so $1-E=(1/2) (1/4)+(1/2)(1/4)=1/4$, and for the bigger piece $E=3/4$.

3) Yet another approach to the continuous stick question is to use areas to stand in for integrals. Namely, the expectation is the average value. In the case at hand it's the average value of the function $  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1-x,  & \text{if $x < \frac{1}{2}$} \\
x & \text{if $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$}
\end{cases}$

that you have defined.
The average of a non-negative $f(x)$ on an interval is by definition the area below the curve ("the sum of the values") divided by the length of the interval ("the number of elements being summed"). For the function $f$ above the figure between the graph and the x-axis is a the unit square minus the triangle with vertices at $(0,1)$, $(1/2, 1/2)$ and $(1,1)$ (draw a picture); the missing triangle has area $1/4$, so the subgraph area is $3/4$. Since the length of the interval is 1, the average is $(3/4)/1=3/4$.

Answer (score 1):

*A detailed answer... if you are willing to replace integration by a symmetry argument.*

Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and $X = \max(U,1-U)$, $Y = \min(U,1-U)$. You want $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

Note that $X+Y=1$, while $X=Y = |X-Y| = |2U-1| = 2|U-\frac{1}{2}|$. So
$$\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = 1\tag{1}$$
while
$$\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[X-Y] = 2\mathbb{E}[|U-1/2|]\tag{2}$$
so that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+2\mathbb{E}[|U-1/2|]\right) \tag{3}
$$
To compute $\mathbb{E}[|U-1/2|]$ without integration, you can note that $V=U-1/2$ is uniform on $[-1/2,1/2]$; *by symmetry*, one can see $V$ as
$$
V = \begin{cases} W &\text{ w.p. } 1/2\\ -W &\text{ w.p. } 1/2\\\end{cases}
$$
where $W$ is uniform on $[0,1/2]$, so that $|U-1/2|=|V| = W$ has expectation 
$\mathbb{E}[W]=1/4$.

This leads to
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+2\cdot \frac{1}{4}\right) = \boxed{\frac{3}{4}} \tag{3}
$$